# Puppeteer returns blank screenshot of NextJS page

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, next.js, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer with Lambda to render screenshots from pages by URL parameter.
The page that I want to render is created with NextJS. There are no firewalls that might prevent rendering, and randomly Puppeteer renders blank white screenshots. I've tried https://google.com but it always renders correct screenshot.

The page that I want to screenshot just renders Chart.js without animations, moreover data is fetched on server side, so there no many client side blockers.

You can check endpoint by following [URL](https://7fkwqu5h0h.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?width=700&height=300&url=https://widgets.askfinny.com/workplace/609d75b2cd28d901a206ace0/chart?name=slack_users).

Sometimes I am getting correct view, but randomly I get blank white page.

[image]

[image]

Here the puppeteer code running on AWS Lambda.

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from "aws-lambda";
import chromium from "chrome-aws-lambda";
import { addExtra } from "puppeteer-extra";
import StealthPlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth";

export const screenshot = async (
  event: APIGatewayProxyEvent
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  const url = event.queryStringParameters?.url as string;
  const height = Number(event.queryStringParameters?.height) || 720;
  const width = Number(event.queryStringParameters?.width) || 1280;
  const type = event.queryStringParameters?.type;
  const puppeteer = addExtra(chromium.puppeteer as any);
  puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

  if (!url) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: "please provide a valid page url",
      }),
    };
  }

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
      headless: chromium.headless,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const userAgent =
      "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3738.0 Safari/537.36";
    await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    });

    await page.setViewport({
      height,
      width,
    });

    await page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: ["networkidle0"],
    });

    const rawScreenshot = await page
      .screenshot({
        type: "jpeg",
      })
      .then((res) => res as any)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));

    const html = await page.content();

    await browser.close();

    if (type === "html") {
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "text/html",
        },
        body: html,
      };
    }

    if (type === "base64") {
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        },
        body: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${rawScreenshot.toString("base64")}`,
      };
    }

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
      },
      isBase64Encoded: true,
      body: rawScreenshot.toString("base64"),
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(err, null, 2),
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, the URL you're navigating to is just a screenshot, https://7fkwqu5h0h.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?width=700&height=300&url=https://widgets.askfinny.com/workplace/609d75b2cd28d901a206ace0/chart?name=slack_users? Can you put the actual URL into the code so there's no ambiguity about which page we're automating here? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen given URL is Lambda function which generates image from `url` query string. So the original page you can find/change in url string.

Comment: OK, I understand now, although I refreshed about 30 times and wasn't able to see any problem. How often does it fail?

Comment: @ggorlen I think I could find the culprit! 
Basically if I change some styles to inline, it works. I suppose it's because tailwind styles are slightly heavy and it doesn't manage to load before screenshot. I will write expanded answer shortly!

Comment: Nice find, although shouldn't `networkidle0` handle that? If there's a specific stylesheet resource, you could use `page.waitForResponse` to wait for it specifically.

Comment: @ggorlen I think it's supposed to behave so, but for some reason it didn't behave so. Moreover, I've tried bunch of other stuff, such as simply adding timeout or utilized `waitForFunction` with timeout from client page without success. 

Although just leveraging on inline style for such small elements is better for the page as well